# Как определить какая тень у кнопки (длина, цвет, расположение)

Tags: css3

Задание сверстать кнопку у которой есть тень. Сама кнопка расположена в блоке на градиентном фоне. Файл не PSD, а скриншот. Собственно возникает вопрос из заголовка моего вопроса. Как это правильно делается, не на глаз же?

Comment: До того, как задание дали, вам всего этого не объяснили? Какой параметр за что отвечает?

Comment: Есть только скриншот.

Comment: Ну есть скрин...  А где попытки? Что именно не получается?

Comment: На сайте не принято отвечать на вопросы с заданиями, если нет попыток автора...   Покажи что сам наработал, что именно не получается...

Comment: А что, знаешь ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно поставить какое-нибудь расширение для браузера. Лично я когда верстал, использовал в таких случаях [Perfect Pixel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi?hl=ru). Просто в него грузишь свой скриншот, настраиваешь прозрачность и в консоли разработчика балуешься со свойствами, пока все не совпадет. Тем более у вас на скриншоте, по вашим словам, масштаб 1 к 1, то есть проблем возникнуть не должно

Comment: Немного задача усложняется скрин не 1:1

Comment: @ikar в этом плагине есть возможность изменять масштаб макета. Если блок под кнопкой уже сверстан, можно под него подогнать и тогда уже делать саму кнопку

Comment: А если сделать PrtScrn и в Photoshop, масштаб поставить 100%, далее установить направляющие и вычесть размер?

Comment: @ikar можно и так, но как по мне - проще с подобным плагином работать. у тебя будет полупрозрачный макет наложенный на страницу, которую верстаешь и уже там можно подгонять с точностью до пикселя, пока реальный блок и картинка не совпадут полностью